# #define and how to use them - C++

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, precompiled-headers

In a pre-compiled header if I do:

```
#define DS_BUILD
#define PGE_BUILD
#define DEMO
```

then in source I do:

```
#if (DS_BUILD && DEMO)
    ---- code---
#elif (PGE_BUILD && DEMO)
    --- code---
#else
    --- code ---
#endif
```

Do I get an error that states:

> error: operator '&&' has no right operand

I have never seen this before. I am using XCode 3.2, GCC 4.2 on OS X 10.6.3

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to add the [defined](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.0.1/cpp_4.html#SEC39) keyword since you want to check that you defined have been defined.

```
#if defined (DS_BUILD) && defined (DEMO)
    ---- code---
#elif defined (PGE_BUILD) && defined (DEMO)
    --- code---
#else
    --- code ---
#endif
```

Comment: Alternatively you could #define DEMO 1

Answer (score 4):

You have to decide first how you want to use your conditional compilation macros. There are normally two popular approaches. It is either

```
#define A
#define B

#ifdef A
...
#endif

#if defined(A) && defined(B)
...
#endif
```

or

```
#define A 1
#define B 0

#if A
...
#endif

#if A && B
...
#endif
```

I.e. either just define a macro and analyze it with `#ifdef` and/or `#if defined()` or define a macro for a numerical value and analyze if with `#if`.

You are mixing these two approaches in your code sample, which generally makes no sense. Decide which approach you want to use and stick to it.

Answer (score 2):

The effect of `#define DEMO` is that during preprocessing every occurence of `DEMO` is replaced with nothing ( `''` ). The same with `#define PGE_BUILD`. So, in the second sample you posted you effectively get `#elif ( && )` which, you agree, doesn't make much sense for compiler:).

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide values for `DS_BUILD` , `PGE_BUILD` and `DEMO`, or you need to use ifdef

```
#define DS_BUILD 1
#define PGE_BUILD 1
#define DEMO 1
```

defining like above would work